# My screen is messed up after uninstalling ros. What is the problem? Please refer to the details for the full question

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm new to Linux. I have installed Kubuntu on an acer Aspire 5040 for a project at school. I had also installed ROS on it and had been using the laptop to go through ROS tutorials. I had originally installed ROS fuerte on it but at some point I installed ROS groovy alongside fuerte. Due to some problems I decided to uninstall ROS all together. This is the command I used:

sudo apt-get remove ros-*

After it was completely uninstalled I turned off my laptop. The next day when I powered it back on, it would bring up the login window, but after loggin in I would see a black and white striped screen. Did I uninstall some drivers while I was trying to uninstall ROS? How can I make it work again? I would really appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191603/my-screen-is-messed-up-after-uninstalling-ros.-what-is-the-problem?-please-refer-to-the-details-for-the-full-question/) by [Pa El](https://answers.ros.org/users/20112/pa-el/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's hard to say exactly what else was uninstalled when you removed ROS. You may want to review your dpkg log ( /var/log/dpkg.log ), and check the login type.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0